# How to parse a line which has a number after a certain string greater than a threshold?

Tags: awk, grep, json

I have a file (list_20.txt) that looks like this:

```
[{"d_prime":"0.475425","variation1":"rs909776","r2":"0.057940","variation2":"rs16991816","population_name":"1000GENOMES:phase_3:KHV"}]
[{"r2":"0.057940","variation1":"rs909776","d_prime":"0.475425","population_name":"1000GENOMES:phase_3:KHV","variation2":"rs16991819"}]
[{"variation1":"rs909776","r2":"0.078476","d_prime":"0.546491","population_name":"1000GENOMES:phase_3:KHV","variation2":"rs8114269"}]
[{"population_name":"1000GENOMES:phase_3:KHV","variation2":"rs8114269","r2":"0.073418","variation1":"rs6130034","d_prime":"0.528588"}]
[{"population_name":"1000GENOMES:phase_3:KHV","variation2":"rs1201686","r2":"0.060239","variation1":"rs3746539","d_prime":"0.271891"}]
[{"variation2":"rs1201686","population_name":"1000GENOMES:phase_3:KHV","d_prime":"0.280262","r2":"0.058212","variation1":"rs2144011"}]
[{"population_name":"1000GENOMES:phase_3:KHV","variation2":"rs10485662","r2":"0.058826","variation1":"rs844808","d_prime":"0.423639"}]
[{"variation2":"rs6065565","population_name":"1000GENOMES:phase_3:KHV","d_prime":"0.638509","r2":"0.110749","variation1":"rs6139746"}]
[{"r2":"0.110749","variation1":"rs6139746","d_prime":"0.638509","population_name":"1000GENOMES:phase_3:KHV","variation2":"rs6072936"}]
[{"population_name":"1000GENOMES:phase_3:KHV","variation2":"rs6065562","variation1":"rs6139746","r2":"0.091021","d_prime":"0.606214"}]
[{"variation1":"rs6139746","r2":"0.910749","d_prime":"0.638509","population_name":"1000GENOMES:phase_3:KHV","variation2":"rs6072937"}]
...
```

I would like to extract only lines that have value after "r2":" greater than 0.7 and less or equal 1

in this example the expected output would be just this line:

```
[{"variation1":"rs6139746","r2":"0.910749","d_prime":"0.638509","population_name":"1000GENOMES:phase_3:KHV","variation2":"rs6072937"}]
```

I tried this:

```
awk '$NF >= 0.8 && $NF <1 {print $0}' list_20.txt  > 20.out
```

but I got an empty file. Also this command is not specific to the string of interest: "r2":"

Comment: Can u confirm the input file... Is this how it exactly looks ?

Comment: yes it does look exactly like that, no specific columns

Comment: Plz share the expected output

Comment: the expected output is in my post and for the example given it is [{"variation1":"rs6139746","r2":"0.910749","d_prime":"0.638509","population_name":"1000GENOMES:phase_3:KHV","variation2":"rs6072937"}]

Comment: Your input looks like json - is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk -F'[][{},]' '{
  for (i=3;i<=NF-2;i++){
    if ($i ~ /^"r2"/){
      r2=substr($i, 7, length($i)-7)
      if (r2>0.7 && r2<=1){ print; break }
    }
  }
}' list_20.txt > 20.out
```

Use `]`, `[`, `{`, `}` and `,` as field separators. Then loop over the fields in each record skipping the first two and last two fields (since they are always empty).

Test if the current field starts with `"r2"` and extract the value with `substr($i, 7, length($i)-7)`, i.e. skip the first 6 characters `"r2":"` and omit the last character `"`.

Print the record if the value is within the range and break the loop.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much for the explanation, ti makes sense!!!

Answer (score 4):

Since this looks like JSON, let's use a command line JSON parser:

```
$ jq '.[] | select((.r2|tonumber) > 0.7 and (.r2|tonumber) <= 1)' file
{
  "variation1": "rs6139746",
  "r2": "0.910749",
  "d_prime": "0.638509",
  "population_name": "1000GENOMES:phase_3:KHV",
  "variation2": "rs6072937"
}
```

We have to convert the values of the `r2` keys to proper numbers from strings with `tonumber`, but apart from that, it's a simple filter through `select()`.

We can shorten it somewhat, or at least avoid converting each number *twice*, with

```
jq '.[] | (.r2|tonumber) as $r2 | select($r2 > 0.7 and $r2 <= 1)' file
```

Would you want to have the results on the same format as the input, use

```
$ jq -c '.[] | (.r2|tonumber) as $r2 | select($r2 > 0.7 and $r2 <= 1) | [.]' file
[{"variation1":"rs6139746","r2":"0.910749","d_prime":"0.638509","population_name":"1000GENOMES:phase_3:KHV","variation2":"rs6072937"}]
```

That is, ask for "compact output" with `-c` and create an array for each result extracted via the `select()` filter using `[.]`.

Answer (score 1):

With Awk:

```
awk 'match($0, /"r2":"[^"]+"/) {
  t = substr($0, RSTART+6, RLENGTH-7)
  f = 0.7<t+0 && t+0<=1
  if ( f ) print 
}' list_20.txt
```

You can do this in perl also:

```
perl -lne '
  print if /"r2":"(.*?)"/ and 0.7<$1 && $1<=1;
' list_20.txt
```

We are looking for the string  r2 in quotes and what follows it. Then the condition for range check is applied and then the line is printed if found within range.

Answer (score 0):

Provided the numbers are floating point you can grep out the lines like this:

```
$  LC_ALL=C grep -E '"r2":"((0?\.(7[0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*|[89][0-9]*))|1(\.0*)?)"' list_20.txt
```

`-E`   option turns on the extended regex

Comment: Fixed the regex error and also provided the locale environment. Thanks.

Comment: How about `0.71`? I suppose we can assume there won't be any 7.2e-1.

Comment: It is clearly mentioned that floating points are assumed here. The regex has been updated to handle numbers >.7 now.

Comment: `7.2e-1` is a floating point number, but it's not what `printf %g` would typically output for `0.72`. But see for instance: `echo '[7.2e-1,0.000072]' | jq -c` which gives `[0.72,7.2e-05]` confirming that while that json tool would render 0.72 as 0.72, scientific notation may be used for some numbers, so that kind of approach may need to be adapted depending on how the json content has been generated, and the number range to match (think for instance a `0` to `1` range)

Answer (score 0):

Not a efficient method but my try

```
sed 's/[\["{}]//g' i.txt| sed 's/\]//g'|sed 's/,/ /g'| awk -F ":" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if ($i ~ /r2/ && $(i+1) > 0.7) {print $0}}}'| perl -pne "s/ /\n/g"| sed 's/^/"/g'|sed 's/$/"/g'| perl -pne 's/\n/,/g'| sed 's/^/[{/g'| sed 's/$/}]/g'| sed "s/,}]/}]/g"
```

output

```
[{"variation1:rs6139746","r2:0.910749","d_prime:0.638509","population_name:1000GENOMES:phase_3:KHV","variation2:rs6072937"}]
```

Comment: Instead of piping through three `sed` calls, combine them into one. I count no more than 8 separate calls to `sed`, one `awk` and two calls to `perl`. You should be able to do it all in Perl or `awk`.

Comment: WIll improve on this Thanks for input